# HTML email - Outlook adding 1px padding left and top of images (PNG / background color)

Tags: html, email, outlook

I'm trying to place a transparent PNG* over a background color so i can make a series of emails and only have to change the background color.  Outlook** is adding a 1px padding / margin to the left and top of the image allowing the background color to show through.

[1px green lines left / top of white boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYGvM.jpg)

How do i get rid of the padding so that the image is flush against the edge?

- Also happens with JPGs as well.

** I have no idea what version of Outlook I have.  It's "desktop," not "mobile."  Here's the spec:
Microsoft® Outlook® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2210 Build 16.0.15726.20070) 64-bit

Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Untitled</title>

    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <xml>
    <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
    <o:AllowPNG/>
    <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
    </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
    </xml>
    <![endif]-->

    <style type="text/css">

    html,  body {margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important; height: 100% !important; width: 100% !important;}

    * {-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;}

    .ExternalClass {width: 100%;}

    div[style*="margin: 16px 0"] {margin: 0 !important;}

    table,  td {mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important; mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;}

    table {border-spacing: 0 !important; border-collapse: collapse !important; table-layout: fixed !important; margin: 0 auto !important;}
    table table table {table-layout: auto;}

    img {-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;}

    .yshortcuts a {border-bottom: none !important;}

    a[x-apple-data-detectors] {color: inherit !important;}
    </style>

    <style type="text/css">

        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

            .email-container {width: 100% !important;}
            .fluid, .fluid-centered {max-width: 100% !important; height: auto !important; margin-left: auto !important; margin-right: auto !important;}
            .fluid-centered {margin-left: auto !important; margin-right: auto !important;}
            .stack-column, .stack-column-center {display: block !important; width: 100% !important; max-width: 100% !important; direction: ltr !important;}
            .stack-column-center {text-align: center !important;}
        
            .center-on-narrow {text-align: center !important; display: block !important; margin-left: auto !important; margin-right: auto !important; float: none !important;}
            table.center-on-narrow {display: inline-block !important;}}

    </style>

    </head>

    <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="100%" style="margin: 0px;" yahoo="yahoo">
    <table width="100%" height="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 0px;">
      <tr>
        <td><center style="width: 100%;">
            
            <!-- Visually Hidden Preheader Text : BEGIN -->
            <div style="display: none; mso-hide: all; overflow: hidden; opacity: 0; max-width: 0px; max-height: 0px; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px; mso-height-rule: exactly; color: #FFFFFF;">Untitled</div>
            <!-- Visually Hidden Preheader Text : END --> 

            <!-- Email : BEGIN -->
            <!-- Outer -->
            <table class="email-container" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width: 600px; height: auto; border-collapse: collapse; border: 0px;">
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#767676" style="padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #000000;">

            <!-- Inner -->
                <table width="100%" height="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 0px;">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td bgcolor="#00A261" style="line-height: 10px; mso-height-rule: exactly;"><img src="https://417ee9fcaff7638b6579-b73cd9e67178543aeffbc83afe346fc4.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/CP-2021/14067552-1.jpg" alt="image" style="width: 350px; height: auto; display: block; outline: none; border: 0; margin: 0;"/></td></tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td bgcolor="#00A261" style="line-height: 10px; mso-height-rule: exactly;"><img src="https://417ee9fcaff7638b6579-b73cd9e67178543aeffbc83afe346fc4.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/CP-2021/14067552-1.jpg" alt="image" style="width: 350px; height: auto; display: block; outline: none; border: 0; margin: 0;"/></td></tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>style="display:block; height:auto; outline:none; border:0; margin: 0; text-decoration:none; font-family: 'Campton', arial, sans-serif; font-size:20px; line-height:1.5; color:blue; text-align:center; margin:0;"</td></tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody></table>
            <!-- Inner : END -->

                </td></tr></table></center></td></tr></table></body></html>
```

I've tried everything!  Oddly enough, these 1px lines look just like the grey lines around the "Download Images" icon before downloading the images when the email arrives.

Also.  Ran this through Emails On Acid.  These lines do not display on any of the renderings.  (At least, not that i saw.)

Answer (score 0):

At last Microsoft has released an update that resolved this issue. Now the version of my Outlook is 2212.